# uncommittable transaction is detected at the end of batch. the transaction is rolled back

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are having problem with the server migration. We have one application that are having
so much transactions It working fine on the one database server. But when transfer same database to another server. We are facing the following error.

> `Server: Msg 3998, Level 16, State 1, Line 1`
>   `Uncommittable transaction is
>   detected at the end of the batch. The
>   transaction is rolled back.`

Same database is copied to the another server with the all data. If we change connectionstring to old server then it is working fine.

Can anybody suggest on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you seem to have is a problem where the record is acceptable in one database but not theother. Suggest you look at the differnces between the two database structures (yes I know they are supposed to be the same, but clearly they are not). Suspect you will either find a collation difference, a data type differnce, or a data length differnce between the two. YOu might also have a table where the identity definition is missing and thus it can't insert becasue it is a required field and the value is missing. Tools like SQl Compare are easy to use to find differences.

Comment: Is there a way in T-SQL to check whether the current transaction is commitable?

Answer (score 2):

This message means one of the other participants in the transaction voted to rollback.  After that the transaction must fail.

So this message is a consequence, rather than a cause.  Are you receiving any earlier / other error messages?

What happens when you run the query from Management Studio?

Comment: SQL management studio shows exact error rather than the wrapper Rollback error message.

Comment: To add to this I'd check if you have ```SET XACT_ABORT ON``` anywhere which was the issue in my case.